# Which set is this bag from? It has mostly azure pieces

Tags: set-identification, lego-dimensions

[image]

Can someone help me figure out which set this is from? Dated 2011.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bag from [Dimensions Starter Pack parts (71200)](https://brickset.com/sets/71200-1/Starter-Pack-parts).

[image: set image]